# Why don't some war assets appear in my list of assets?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've recently completed the missions on Tuchanka and stopped to review my war assets.

I noticed that the Citadel Defense Force, which was updated several times during conversations with the citizenry after Priority:Palaven isn't listed.

Now I'm checking everything and don't see Batarian Fleet asset listed either.

At first I thought this was a updated/awarded issue, but I have other assets that were "updated" and appeared.

Are these war assets waiting for some other trigger to become available or is this another glitch?

Comment: If there is one thing I've learned from being in the Military (U.S. Army) it's just because they are War Assets, does not mean they are YOUR War Assets. Read the Fine Print.

Comment: Can you post a screencap so we can compare?

Comment: @ampersand A screen cap of something that didn't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this with the *Citadel Defence Force* assets as well.

In their case I found that it appeared under the *Alien* category, but only after the second *Priority: Citadel* mission (the first being immediately after Mars) was completed. All the updates you are triggering now will then be listed on that entry.

The *Batarian Fleet* asset will also appear under the *Alien* category of War Assets. I don't recall a similar effect with this asset, but I believe you can trigger an update with a fetch quest (*Kite's Nest: Pillars of Strength*) before triggering the creation of the asset (which is *Citadel: Batarian Codes*, I think).

---

So in general then, it's probably bad form that they are displayed to the user, but yes, it is possible to update a war asset (and see that notice) before getting control of it.